# How to print JSON file Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, json

```
var user_business_data =[  
   {  
      "user_id":"5db3e3b1",
      "blog":{  
         "blog_id":"128c522e"
      },
      "business_units":[  
         {  
            "business_unit_id":"000396c9",
            "viewing":101
         },
         {  
            "business_unit_id":"01821e44",
            "viewing":102
         },
         {  
            "business_unit_id":"02cbcad5",
            "viewing":103
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to get all the "business_unit_id" and store in a varible. for this i need get all the "business_unit_id". so i tried to print all the id's with the below code but i was unable to print.

```
if (undefined !== user_business_data.business_units && user_business_data.business_units.length) {
    for(var i=0;i<user_business_data.business_units.length;i++){
         var key = user_business_data.business_units[i];
         console.log("Key : "+key, "Values : "+user_business_data.business_units[key]);
    } 
} else {
    console.log("Undefined value");
}
```

There always i am getting undefined value.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var user_business_data=[{"user_id":"5db3e3b1","blog":{"blog_id":"128c522e"},"business_units":[{"business_unit_id":"000396c9","viewing":101},{"business_unit_id":"01821e44","viewing":102},{"business_unit_id":"02cbcad5","viewing":103}]}]
var unit_ids = [];
user_business_data.forEach(function(user) {
  user.business_units.forEach(function(business) {
    unit_ids.push(business.business_unit_id);
  });
});
console.log(unit_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

user_business_data is an array and not an object.If you want to access any object from an array you have to specify the index as of which position you are referring.Therefore in your example change it to following to work:

```
if (undefined !== user_business_data[0].business_units && user_business_data[0].business_units.length) {
            for(var i=0;i<user_business_data[0].business_units.length;i++){
    var key = user_business_data[0].business_units[i]. business_unit_id;
    console.log("Key : "+key, "Values : "+user_business_data[0].business_units[key]);
} 
        } else {
           console.log("Undefined value");


}
```

Comment: But also, `key` will be an object, so not useful to print

Comment: apart from the syntax error, yes. Why not make a [runnable demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), it's easy enough. Then others can more easily see that your solution is good, and also you can test your own code before you post it :-)

Answer (score 0):

`user_business_data` is an array, not an object, so you either need to loop through it or read a specific index from it.

Also, `key` in your code will be an object (a single business unit object), so you can't print it directly - instead you need to fetch a specific property within the object.

Here's a simple demo reading the first key from the outer array and then listing all the specific properties from the business units. The code can be simplified further potentially, but this illustrates the point:

```js
var user_business_data =

  [{
    "user_id": "5db3e3b1",
    "blog": {
      "blog_id": "128c522e"
    },
    "business_units": [{
        "business_unit_id": "000396c9",
        "viewing": 101
      },
      {
        "business_unit_id": "01821e44",
        "viewing": 102
      },
      {
        "business_unit_id": "02cbcad5",
        "viewing": 103
      }
    ]
  }]

if (undefined !== user_business_data[0].business_units && user_business_data[0].business_units.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < user_business_data[0].business_units.length; i++) {
    var key = user_business_data[0].business_units[i].business_unit_id;
    console.log("Key : " + key, "Values : " + user_business_data[0].business_units[i].viewing);
  }
} else {
  console.log("Undefined value");


}
```

I suggest you get clear in your head the difference between arrays, objects and properties in JSON / JS objects, and then this kind of thing will become trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `user_business_data` is an array, not an object yet you access it like `user_business_data.business_units` instead of `user_business_data[0].business_units`

```js
var user_business_data = [{"user_id": "5db3e3b1","blog": {"blog_id": "128c522e"}, "business_units": [{"business_unit_id": "000396c9","viewing": 101}, {"business_unit_id": "01821e44","viewing": 102},{"business_unit_id": "02cbcad5","viewing": 103}]}];

// Both methods give the same result, but the second checks for null values.
var ids1 = user_business_data[0].business_units.map(x => x.business_unit_id)

console.log('Method 1:', ids1);

// The && check for null values, kinda like an if statement.
var data = user_business_data.length && user_business_data[0]
var units = data && data.business_units
var ids2 = units && units.length && units.map(x => x.business_unit_id)

console.log('Method 2:', ids2)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print only the business_unit_ids then you can do as follows:

```js
var user_business_data =
[
                    {
                       "user_id": "5db3e3b1",
                       "blog": {
                            "blog_id": "128c522e"
                               },
                       "business_units": [
                            {
                                "business_unit_id": "000396c9",             
                                "viewing": 101
                            },
                            {
                                "business_unit_id": "01821e44",              
                                "viewing": 102
                            },
                            {
                                "business_unit_id": "02cbcad5",                
                                "viewing": 103
                            }           
                        ]
                     }
                ]
for(var i=0;i<user_business_data[0]["business_units"].length;i++){
console.log(user_business_data[0]["business_units"][i].business_unit_id)
}
```